# Does facebook insights API return post_impressions_by_story_type for any story type other than comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-insights

Looking over my insights API data for posts, the `post_impressions_by_story_type` metric appears to return only values for impressions generated by the comment story type.

For similar metrics, such as `post_storytellers_by_action_type` the insights API returns values for comment, like, share, follow & answer.

Is this true of the metric itself? Is it possible my content just hasn't generated any impressions through actions/stories other than comments?

Docs simply describe the metric as

> The number of times this post was seen via a story published by a
>   friend of the person viewing the post

Comment: I too am seeing data for type 'comment' only.  I see like, share, and comment for `post_storytellers_by_action_type`

Comment: There should be `like` story-types also in there but they are not showing up when I submit the query.